# Trying to take the last object of an array and move it to the front for movement of snake in vanilla JS/canvas snake game

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been trying to build a snake game app without any tutorials and have been stuck on a logic issue for several days. From the codepen bellow you can see I have my snake moving but it doesn't move like a rope it just moves around as one stuck together unit of 'blocks' or pieces.

I'm sure most of you can do something like this with your eyes closed, but I wondered if you can talk me off a ledge. I wonder if I have put this together in such a way that I need to rethink how I have built it up to this point and maybe (mostly) start over?

On lines 43 - 47 you can see that I have tried to '''pop()''' the last array item out and then '''unshift()''' it back to the front and then paint the new array back to the canvas. Can I do this with JS and Canvas in my '''updateSnake()''' function and if not can you nudge me to where my logic is flawed?

Thanks!

https://codepen.io/constequalsexcel/pen/eYNjRER

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Snake Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <header id="header">Snake Game</header>
  <div id="score-box">
    <h1>SCORE</h1>
    <h3 id="score">0</h3>
  </div>
  <body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
#gameCanvas {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0 100px 0;
  font-size: 35px;
}

#score {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

JS

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let snakeDirection;
document.addEventListener("keydown", moveSnakeKeys, false);
let appleX;
let appleY;
let score = 0;

createApple();

class Snake {
  constructor() {
    this.body = [{ x: 50, y: 200 }, { x: 34, y: 200 }, { x: 18, y: 200 }];
    this.snakeSpeedX = 15;
    this.snakeSpeedY = 15;
    this.color = "green";
    this.snakeSize = 15;
  }

  drawSnake() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.body.length; i++) {
      ctx.fillRect(
        this.body[i].x,
        this.body[i].y,
        this.snakeSize,
        this.snakeSize
      );
    }
    ctx.fill();
  }

  // remove 'tail' from snake
  // store 'tail' in a variable
  // check direction of snake
  // place 'tail' infront of snake body

  updateSnake() {
    if (snakeDirection === "right") {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.body.length; i++) {
        this.body[i].x += this.snakeSpeedX;
        // let tail = this.body.pop()
        // console.log(tail)
        // tail.x = this.body[0].x
        // tail.y = this.body[0].y
        // this.body.unshift(tail)
      }
    } else if (snakeDirection === "down") {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.body.length; i++) {
        this.body[i].y += this.snakeSpeedY;
      }
    } else if (snakeDirection === "left") {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.body.length; i++) {
        this.body[i].x -= this.snakeSpeedX;
      }
    } else if (snakeDirection === "up") {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.body.length; i++) {
        this.body[i].y -= this.snakeSpeedY;
      }
    }
    this.drawSnake();
  }
}

const snake = new Snake();

function animate() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  snake.updateSnake();
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(appleX, appleY, 15, 15);
  ctx.fill();
  updateScore();
  gameOver();
}

setInterval(animate, 200);

function moveSnakeKeys(e) {
  if (e.code === "ArrowRight" && snakeDirection != "left") {
    snakeDirection = "right";
  } else if (e.code === "ArrowLeft" && snakeDirection != "right") {
    snakeDirection = "left";
  } else if (e.code === "ArrowUp" && snakeDirection != "down") {
    snakeDirection = "up";
  } else if (e.code === "ArrowDown" && snakeDirection != "up") {
    snakeDirection = "down";
  }
}

function createApple() {
  appleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - 15));
  appleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height - 15));
}

function updateScore() {
  if (
    snake.body[0].x < appleX + 15 &&
    snake.body[0].x + 15 > appleX &&
    snake.body[0].y < appleY + 15 &&
    snake.body[0].y + 15 > appleY
  ) {
    ctx.clearRect(appleX, appleY, 15, 15);
    createApple();
    score = score + 1;
    document.getElementById("score").innerText = score;
    growSnake();
  }
}

function growSnake() {
  let xLength = snake.body[snake.body.length - 1].x - 16;
  let yLength = snake.body[snake.body.length - 1].y;
  snake.body.push({ x: xLength, y: yLength });
}

function gameOver() {
  if (
    snake.body[0].x > canvas.width - snake.snakeSpeedX ||
    snake.body[0].x < 0
  ) {
    alert("Game Over!");
  } else if (
    snake.body[0].y > canvas.height - snake.snakeSpeedY ||
    snake.body[0].y < 0
  ) {
    alert("Game Over!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is good. The missing piece is actually updating the new head to move in the direction you want.

```
updateSnake() {
  const dir = {
    up: {x: 0, y: -this.snakeSize},
    down: {x: 0, y: this.snakeSize},
    left: {x: -this.snakeSize, y: 0},
    right: {x: this.snakeSize, y: 0},
  }[snakeDirection] || {x: 0, y: 0};
  this.body.unshift(this.body.pop());
  this.body[0].x = this.body[1].x + dir.x;
  this.body[0].y = this.body[1].y + dir.y;
  this.drawSnake();
}
```

The conditional is a bit unsightly, so an object is an easy way to eliminate it. Scope it to the class if you're (rightfully) worried about allocating it every frame.

Since `snakeDirection` is uninitialized at the start of the script, I use `|| {x: 0, y: 0}` to set `dir` to a default value if the `snakeDirection` key wasn't found in the object.

A few other pointers:

- `snakeDirection` being a global is unnecessary, breaking encapsulation. Pass it into `updateSnake` as a parameter.
- Move `this.drawSnake()` out of the `updateSnake` function--better to keep concerns separate and move these function calls to a parent function.
- Similarly, `animate` should not be calling a `gameOver` function. This function doesn't actually cause a game over, so it's somewhat misleadingly named. It checks bounds, which should be the responsibility of a game or snake class. It also spams dialog boxes upon game over but I'm sure that's a WIP.
- Consider using a consistent grid size, like 15 or 20 pixels.
- Use `event.preventDefault()` for keypresses so the screen doesn't shift around while the user is controlling their snake.

Comment: Thanks ggorlen! I'm going to take some time and digest this and how it's working. Thank you for pointing out some of my other flaws as well! I appreciate the time and reply and I'll get working on these pointers.